# open page in new instance of browser

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, browser

please tell me how to open a page on click of hyper link in new browser instance (so that it should not be blocked by popup blocker) in flash AS3/ javascript

Thanks

Comment: Does this sound like something someone is going to want to help you with? You may as well have asked "How should I best annoy my users?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open on a new tab (not on a new browser!) by doing this:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://stackoverflow.com");
navigateToURL(urlRequest, "_blank");
```

Please, use it wisely...

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript

```
// spawnWindow( 'www.duh.com', 'windowRef' )
function spawnWindow(URL, Name) {
  var features = 'toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=0,resizable=0,width=900,height=700';
  window.open(URL, Name, features);
}
```

AS3 code to call JS function

```
var retVal:int = ExternalInterface.call("spawnWindow",address,newId);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible! Unless you use ActiveX.